# Facebook Like Box no longer displays faces or stream

Tags: plugins, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-likebox

I have using facebook plugins in a .net website. Recently they have stopped showing the stream and faces (header displays correctly).

The biggest indicator is if I use the developer toolbox the stream and faces show - the exact same code in my web page and they don't show. They used to display - I'm not sure at what point they have since broken so I can't track my code changes.

My code:
(Placed below the body tag)

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                (function (d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
            </script>
```

(Placed further down the page)

Comment: I knew I'd find it the minute I posted this - I've been looking at this for hours. It was case sensitive. I allow the user to select options for the plugin and it was coming out as True instead of true.